# Change color and format of scaleline

Tags: openlayers, scale-bar

How can I change the format of the scaleline in OpenLayers? I have a black background and I want to change the lines in the scalebar to white. I use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <style type="text/css">
     div.olControlScaleLine{
        color: white;

     }`

But this only change the font. Anybody kmow how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
div.olControlScaleLine{
    color: white;
}

div.olControlScaleLine>div{
   border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: It works, I wanted this.Thx.